# LAG(...) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY....)

Tags: sql, oracle, mariadb, lag

I have an ORACLE SQL that has LAG(...) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY ...) in the code but getting an error when trying to use it in SQL for a MariaDB.  Does anyone know what similar function is for MariaDB?

UPDATE:

The real database I pull from doesn't have the correct step numbers for REWORK steps, so need to tie the step_no to the last row that has MAIN for a step value. As in the table example the desired_results column has step_no 102 for all the REWORK rows, which is from the last MAIN row with 10/10/2018 01:00:03 claim_ts.

Example code:

```
WITH testTable AS (
     SELECT '10/9/2018 17:22:54' AS claim_ts, 'MAIN' AS step, '100' AS step_no, '100' as desired_results UNION ALL
     SELECT '10/9/2018 20:39:32', 'MAIN', '101', '101'   UNION ALL
     SELECT '10/10/2018 01:00:03', 'MAIN', '102', '102' UNION ALL
     SELECT '10/10/2018 01:01:44', 'REWORK', '5', '102' UNION ALL
     SELECT '10/11/2018 05:55:20', 'REWORK', NULL, '102' UNION ALL
     SELECT '10/11/2018 13:12:11', 'REWORK', '5', '102' UNION ALL
     SELECT '10/11/2018 16:45:00', 'REWORK', NULL, '102' UNION ALL
     SELECT '10/12/2018 03:08:25', 'MAIN', '103', '103'
)
SELECT
claim_ts,
step,
step_no,
desired_results
```

FROM testTable

Example of the results.

[image: Example table]

[dbfiddle with code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d0b8d03336a1ef5b9568bb8e1c8cccae)

Comment: You should probably include your query.  Even if MariaDB doesn't support `IGNORE NULLS` there could be a workaround.

Comment: The `desired_results` column does not appear to be a `LAG` of anything.  If you want help to generate that column, you should carefully explain what is going on there.

Comment: I made an update again, hopefully, more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB does not support the `IGNORE NULLS` option.  But, we can simulate `LAG` in MariaDB or MySQL using a correlated subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT
    id,
    col1,
    col2,
    (SELECT t2.col1 FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.id < t1.id AND t2.col1 IS NOT NULL
     ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1) col1_lag
FROM yourTable t1;
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

The output you are expecting in your updated question is not really a lag, but we can use similar logic to get what you want:

```
SELECT
    claim_ts,
    step,
    step_no,
    desired_results,
    (SELECT t2.step_no FROM testTable t2
     WHERE t2.claim_ts <= t1.claim_ts AND t2.step = 'MAIN'
     ORDER BY t2.claim_ts DESC LIMIT 1) AS actual_results
FROM testTable t1;
```

### Demo

Comment: I wasn't sure how to change the id's to use timestamp.  I updated my post with example data.

Comment: @newbie_146 I gave you an option for generating the latest results you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lag/), MariaDB does not support this option:

> ```
> LAG (expr[, offset]) OVER ( 
>   [ PARTITION BY partition_expression ] 
>   < ORDER BY order_list >
> )
> ```

Nor does it seem to support the third argument, which is a default value.

As for a replacement, you should provide sample data and desired results.  It is simpler to provide a solution for particular data.  For instance, if the column you are trying to fill in is increasing (or sometimes `NULL`), then a cumulative max is the simplest solution:

```
max(col) over (order by othercol)
```

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12984
  https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12981